# Swift constant connection with variable to define if statement

Tags: swift

I completed a challenge to create a story app that has different endings depending on the answer you give. And the app works fine but I don't really get it fully. Basically it's a very simple that that just has a UILabel with the text and 2 UIButtons that change every step of the game.

In order to separate our if statements from another we had to create a variable called `storyIndex` that we put after the `sender.tag ==`.

Code looks like this :

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 1 && storyIndex == 1 {

        storyTextView.text = story3
        topButton.setTitle(answer3a, for: .normal)
        bottomButton.setTitle(answer3b, for: .normal)
        storyIndex = 3

    }

    else if sender.tag == 2 && storyIndex == 1 {

        storyTextView.text = story2
        topButton.setTitle(answer2a, for: .normal)
        bottomButton.setTitle(answer2b, for: .normal)
        storyIndex = 2
    }

    else if sender.tag == 1 && storyIndex == 3 {

        storyTextView.text = story6
        storyIndex = 6
        topButton.isHidden = true
        bottomButton.isHidden = true
    }

    else if sender.tag == 2 && storyIndex == 3 {
        storyTextView.text = story5
        storyIndex = 5
        topButton.isHidden = true
        bottomButton.isHidden = true

    }

    else if sender.tag == 1 && storyIndex == 2 {

        storyTextView.text = story3
        topButton.setTitle(answer3a, for: .normal)
        bottomButton.setTitle(answer3b, for: .normal)
        storyIndex = 3
        }

    else if sender.tag == 2 && storyIndex == 2 {

        storyTextView.text = story4
        storyIndex = 4
        topButton.isHidden = true
        bottomButton.isHidden = true
    }
```

and the variable was put below the IBoutlets connections:

```
var storyIndex : Int = 1
```

and the top of the code just below the class we had our constants containing the story text:

eg:

```
let story1 = "Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: \"Need a ride, boy?\"."
```

So I finally figure out how to do it with little help from the Q&A tab but really I don't get how Swift knows that `storyIndex` let's say 2 is a story 2 ? where do I define that, basically where is the connection between the constants and the variable `storyIndex`. Does the word Index works like that ? Or did I define it?

Wouldn't be easier just to do something like this?

```
if sender.tag == 1 && storyTextView.text == (\story1) {
```

Sorry about my English, it's my third language.

Comment: Swift doesn't know that, you have decided that with your `if` conditions and what gets done if they are true.

Comment: Yes i know that, i just would like to know how does Xcode knows that storyIndex = 1 is really a let story1

Comment: Xcode doesn't know that and it is not a direct relation ship. Look at the code there are to conditions for storyIndex = 1 for instance and you get a different story depending on what tag it is.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted simply runs when the button is pushed.  The button is determined based on the `tag` property, which is set in the InterfaceBuilder.  Looks like action 1 is `tag = 1` is previous and action 2 is `tag = 2` is next.

Then, the code looks at current story index and the button pushed (`tag`), and determines what the the next story index is and sets the appropriate story text.

The reason it's not comparing story text is story text doesn't really give you an easy way to see where in the story you are unless you read the text.  Also, comparing strings takes longer than comparing integers, although in this case it would be negligible.

Here, the mapping between the index and the story text is done inside each if statement.  A better way would be to have an array that has story text indexed by story index (eg: `storyText[storyIndex]`).